# Datadog regex to find a text that has double quote

Tags: regex, datadog

I have logs that contain this kind of line:

```
..."event_artist_id": 100, "event_artist_name": "Elton John"...
```

I want to filter out ones with `"event_artist_id": 100`

How do I do that?

I tried many options, but no luck yet, for example: `\/"event_artist_id": 100\/*`

Comment: You want to filter any text with double quotes or the text 'event_artist_id' is to be filtered out? Also, the number is variable ? `\"event_artist_id\"\s*:\s*[\d]+`

Comment: @n1colas.m, updated

Comment: I think `grep` is able to do just that. To search the lines NOT containing some string, there is a command line switch. Just give it a try.